# How to request flex.messaging.io.ArrayCollection as Externalized Object in FluorineFx for C#?

Tags: c#, amf, fluorinefx

currently I am developing C# application that sends amf packet to server using FluorineFx.

It works fine, but I found out strange datatype called Externalized Object.

I cannot find out what kind of datatype that is from wikipedia.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_Message_Format

[image]

This is the capture file from Charles and I have re-produce those Externalized Objects.

My C# code is pretty simple as below.

[image]

But I get error from the server.

Anyone can help me this code?

**EDIT**

I cannot even send as Externalized Object data type.

[image]

Comment: What error do you get back from the server?

Comment: @NexTerren java.lang.ClassCastException : [Ljava.lang.Object; incompatible with java.util.List